# Five-digit number N puzzle

Tags: python

> **Here is an old puzzle question you can solve with a computer program. There is only one
> five-digit number n that is such that every one of the following ten numbers shares exactly
> one digit in common in the same position as n. Find n.**
>
>  
>  The numbers are: 01265, 12171, 23257, 34548, 45970, 56236, 67324, 78084, 89872, 99414

Kindly help. I don't know how to attack the problem anymore. My code only identified the common digits along with the corresponding indices.

```
from itertools import combinations

def common(a,b):
    count = [(i, int(a[i])) for i in range(5) if a[i] == b[i]]
    return count

l = ['01265', '12171', '23257', '34548', '45970', '56236', '67324', '78084', '89872', '99414']
combi = list(combinations(l, 2))
same = []
for x in combi:
    y = eval('common' + str(x))
    if len(y) != 0 and y not in same:
        same.append(y)
print(sorted(same))
```

Comment: `y = eval('common' + str(x))` ???  `y = common(*x)` !

Comment: Oh yeah thanks. Hahaha, how 'bout the whole problem tho :(

Comment: `if len(y) != 0 and y not in same:` could be rewritten as `if y and y not in same:` and `same` should probably be a set (although with that few items in it searching `in` with that list probably fine as is...

Comment: This is indeed an interesting problem. Similar logic to the [mastermind board game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mastermind_(board_game)). I will have a go when I find the time

Comment: Would numpy arrays be a good way to solve it? I was thinking to convert l into `vec = np.array(l, dtype=int)`, and do some exclusion checks on each index in all vector rows, until only one digit remains for each which would be the target n.

Answer (score 1):

Okay I def overthinked this one. I thought that running a for loop for all 5-digit integers would be heavy for Python even with the conditions. I was wrong.
Here's the simple code :(

```
def common(a,b):
    count = [a[i] for i in range(5) if a[i] == b[i]]
    return len(count)
l = ['01265','12171', '23257', '34548', '45970', '56236', '67324', '78084', '89872', '99414']
for i in range(10000, 100000):
    for x in l:
        if common(str(i), x) != 1:
            break
    else:
        print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this when searching for help for this puzzle in Brian Heinold's a practical introduction to python
8.7 Exercises
25 There is only one five-digit number n that is such that every one of the following ten numbers shares exactly one digit in common in the same position as n. Find n.
As not up to functions yet (def?) and I wanted to understand the solution better I did a much less elegant solution, but maybe someone will find it a bit useful. My first post so hope I did nothing wrong;

```
LST = ['01265','12171', '23257', '34548', '45970', '56236', '67324', '78084', '89872', '99414']
print(LST)
for i in range(10000,100000):
    all_ok = 'y'
    for c in range(len(LST)):
        cnt = 0
        for r in range(len(LST[0])):
            if LST[c][r:r+1] == str(i)[r:r+1]:
             cnt += 1
        if cnt != 1:
            all_ok = 'n'
            break
    if all_ok == 'y':
        print('number is', i)
```